# Windows 7 F6 Drivers off a USB Drive

Tags: windows-7, installation, drivers

I'm doing a fresh install of Windows 7 and I have an on board software RAID. I "need" to install the drivers via the infamous F6 process. Technically, it should be possible to do so after the OS has been booted, but long story short, this isn't going to work well for me.

Is it possible to install F6 drivers during the installation using a USB, or must that always be done using floppies? What are my alternatives?

Comment: Bonus: You don't need to sit around and stay ready to tap F6 anymore :-) You can load the necessary drivers in the GUI under the advanced drive options menu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows Vista or Windows 7 does not use F6 to load drivers.

.
[image]

Comment: +1 I don't miss the F6 screen at all...

Comment: I wept with joy when I installed Vista RC and saw that new feature, then I wept with equal sadness and frustration when I started using Vista.

Comment: Ha ha! Oh well, silly alt, that's what that option is for.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it with a USB drive, or any storage attached via usb, I had to use a USB attached DVD drive for my laptop. The support for USB attached devices while installing 3rd party drivers during install is way better in Windows 7 then it was in XP.